# Do comment votes count against the Electorate badge?

Tags: discussion, comments, voting, electorate-badge

The title says it all. I couldn't find any inkling of information about this in the other Electorate threads.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. Comment votes are only used for display purposes and for the Pundit badge.

The "total votes" in the badge description is referring to the number you can see in your profile (upvotes + downvotes).